# Microsoft.Samples.GZipEncoder with [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json]?

Tags: wcf, gzip, webhttpbinding

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601136/how-to-do-compression-in-a-restful-wcf-service-returning-json) and [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/8c3eafae-b6a1-441f-85ef-90721d941a1a) I've managed to get WebHttpBinding to work with compression (by means of copy-pasting the code). When pointing the browser to my service method, it downloads a file which I can rename to .zip and decompress, so the compression part works. But I'm not able to use Json instead of XML. When I add the webget attribute to the method I just get "[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request."

Also the GZipMessageEncoder.WriteMessage isn't even called. What do I need to change in order to get this working with Json ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the post on MSDN, you'd also need to override the `MessageEncoder.IsContentTypeSupported` to make sure that the gzip encoder also accepts JSON.

The code below has the modified version of that code. I also added a message inspector to add a `Content-Encoding` header, which will allow the browsers to understand the data as-is.

```
public class StackOverflow_14602036
{
    [DataContract]
    public class MyDC
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string str;
        [DataMember]
        public int[] intArray;

        public static MyDC CreateLargeInstance(int size)
        {
            Random rndGen = new Random(1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            MyDC result = new MyDC();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                sb.Append((char)rndGen.Next('a', 'z'));
            }

            result.str = sb.ToString();
            result.intArray = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                result.intArray[i] = rndGen.Next();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        MyDC GetLargeData(int size);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public MyDC GetLargeData(int size)
        {
            return MyDC.CreateLargeInstance(size);
        }
    }

    #region Gzip Encoder Sample
    //This class is used to create the custom encoder (GZipMessageEncoder)
    internal class GZipMessageEncoderFactory : MessageEncoderFactory
    {
        MessageEncoder encoder;

        //The GZip encoder wraps an inner encoder
        //We require a factory to be passed in that will create this inner encoder
        public GZipMessageEncoderFactory(MessageEncoderFactory messageEncoderFactory)
        {
            if (messageEncoderFactory == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("messageEncoderFactory", "A valid message encoder factory must be passed to the GZipEncoder");
            encoder = new GZipMessageEncoder(messageEncoderFactory.Encoder);

        }

        //The service framework uses this property to obtain an encoder from this encoder factory
        public override MessageEncoder Encoder
        {
            get { return encoder; }
        }

        public override MessageVersion MessageVersion
        {
            get { return encoder.MessageVersion; }
        }

        //This is the actual GZip encoder
        class GZipMessageEncoder : MessageEncoder
        {
            static string GZipContentType = "application/x-gzip";

            //This implementation wraps an inner encoder that actually converts a WCF Message
            //into textual XML, binary XML or some other format. This implementation then compresses the results.
            //The opposite happens when reading messages.
            //This member stores this inner encoder.
            MessageEncoder innerEncoder;

            //We require an inner encoder to be supplied (see comment above)
            internal GZipMessageEncoder(MessageEncoder messageEncoder)
                : base()
            {
                if (messageEncoder == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("messageEncoder", "A valid message encoder must be passed to the GZipEncoder");
                innerEncoder = messageEncoder;
            }

            //public override string CharSet
            //{
            //    get { return ""; }
            //}

            public override string ContentType
            {
                get { return GZipContentType; }
            }

            public override string MediaType
            {
                get { return GZipContentType; }
            }

            //SOAP version to use - we delegate to the inner encoder for this
            public override MessageVersion MessageVersion
            {
                get { return innerEncoder.MessageVersion; }
            }

            public override bool IsContentTypeSupported(string contentType)
            {
                return this.innerEncoder.IsContentTypeSupported(contentType);
            }

            //Helper method to compress an array of bytes
            static ArraySegment<byte> CompressBuffer(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                memoryStream.Write(buffer.Array, 0, messageOffset);

                using (GZipStream gzStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                {
                    gzStream.Write(buffer.Array, messageOffset, buffer.Count);
                }


                byte[] compressedBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                byte[] bufferedBytes = bufferManager.TakeBuffer(compressedBytes.Length);

                Array.Copy(compressedBytes, 0, bufferedBytes, 0, compressedBytes.Length);

                bufferManager.ReturnBuffer(buffer.Array);
                ArraySegment<byte> byteArray = new ArraySegment<byte>(bufferedBytes, messageOffset, compressedBytes.Length - messageOffset);

                return byteArray;
            }

            //Helper method to decompress an array of bytes
            static ArraySegment<byte> DecompressBuffer(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager)
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, buffer.Count - buffer.Offset);
                MemoryStream decompressedStream = new MemoryStream();
                int totalRead = 0;
                int blockSize = 1024;
                byte[] tempBuffer = bufferManager.TakeBuffer(blockSize);
                using (GZipStream gzStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = gzStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, blockSize);
                        if (bytesRead == 0)
                            break;
                        decompressedStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        totalRead += bytesRead;
                    }
                }
                bufferManager.ReturnBuffer(tempBuffer);

                byte[] decompressedBytes = decompressedStream.ToArray();
                byte[] bufferManagerBuffer = bufferManager.TakeBuffer(decompressedBytes.Length + buffer.Offset);
                Array.Copy(buffer.Array, 0, bufferManagerBuffer, 0, buffer.Offset);
                Array.Copy(decompressedBytes, 0, bufferManagerBuffer, buffer.Offset, decompressedBytes.Length);

                ArraySegment<byte> byteArray = new ArraySegment<byte>(bufferManagerBuffer, buffer.Offset, decompressedBytes.Length);
                bufferManager.ReturnBuffer(buffer.Array);

                return byteArray;
            }


            //One of the two main entry points into the encoder. Called by WCF to decode a buffered byte array into a Message.
            public override Message ReadMessage(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, string contentType)
            {
                //Decompress the buffer
                ArraySegment<byte> decompressedBuffer = DecompressBuffer(buffer, bufferManager);
                //Use the inner encoder to decode the decompressed buffer
                Message returnMessage = innerEncoder.ReadMessage(decompressedBuffer, bufferManager);
                returnMessage.Properties.Encoder = this;
                return returnMessage;
            }

            //One of the two main entry points into the encoder. Called by WCF to encode a Message into a buffered byte array.
            public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
            {
                //Use the inner encoder to encode a Message into a buffered byte array
                ArraySegment<byte> buffer = innerEncoder.WriteMessage(message, maxMessageSize, bufferManager, messageOffset);
                //Compress the resulting byte array
                return CompressBuffer(buffer, bufferManager, messageOffset);
            }

            public override Message ReadMessage(System.IO.Stream stream, int maxSizeOfHeaders, string contentType)
            {
                GZipStream gzStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
                return innerEncoder.ReadMessage(gzStream, maxSizeOfHeaders);
            }

            public override void WriteMessage(Message message, System.IO.Stream stream)
            {
                using (GZipStream gzStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                {
                    innerEncoder.WriteMessage(message, gzStream);
                }

                // innerEncoder.WriteMessage(message, gzStream) depends on that it can flush data by flushing 
                // the stream passed in, but the implementation of GZipStream.Flush will not flush underlying
                // stream, so we need to flush here.
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
    // This is constants for GZip message encoding policy.
    static class GZipMessageEncodingPolicyConstants
    {
        public const string GZipEncodingName = "GZipEncoding";
        public const string GZipEncodingNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/mspolicy/netgzip1";
        public const string GZipEncodingPrefix = "gzip";
    }

    //This is the binding element that, when plugged into a custom binding, will enable the GZip encoder
    public sealed class GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement
                        : MessageEncodingBindingElement //BindingElement
                        , IPolicyExportExtension
    {

        //We will use an inner binding element to store information required for the inner encoder
        MessageEncodingBindingElement innerBindingElement;

        //By default, use the default text encoder as the inner encoder
        public GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement()
            : this(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement()) { }

        public GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageEncodingBindingElement messageEncoderBindingElement)
        {
            this.innerBindingElement = messageEncoderBindingElement;
        }

        public MessageEncodingBindingElement InnerMessageEncodingBindingElement
        {
            get { return innerBindingElement; }
            set { innerBindingElement = value; }
        }

        //Main entry point into the encoder binding element. Called by WCF to get the factory that will create the
        //message encoder
        public override MessageEncoderFactory CreateMessageEncoderFactory()
        {
            return new GZipMessageEncoderFactory(innerBindingElement.CreateMessageEncoderFactory());
        }

        public override MessageVersion MessageVersion
        {
            get { return innerBindingElement.MessageVersion; }
            set { innerBindingElement.MessageVersion = value; }
        }

        public override BindingElement Clone()
        {
            return new GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement(this.innerBindingElement);
        }

        public override T GetProperty<T>(BindingContext context)
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas))
            {
                return innerBindingElement.GetProperty<T>(context);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.GetProperty<T>(context);
            }
        }

        public override IChannelFactory<TChannel> BuildChannelFactory<TChannel>(BindingContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            context.BindingParameters.Add(this);
            return context.BuildInnerChannelFactory<TChannel>();
        }

        public override IChannelListener<TChannel> BuildChannelListener<TChannel>(BindingContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            context.BindingParameters.Add(this);
            return context.BuildInnerChannelListener<TChannel>();
        }

        public override bool CanBuildChannelListener<TChannel>(BindingContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            context.BindingParameters.Add(this);
            return context.CanBuildInnerChannelListener<TChannel>();
        }

        void IPolicyExportExtension.ExportPolicy(MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext policyContext)
        {
            if (policyContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("policyContext");
            }
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            policyContext.GetBindingAssertions().Add(document.CreateElement(
                GZipMessageEncodingPolicyConstants.GZipEncodingPrefix,
                GZipMessageEncodingPolicyConstants.GZipEncodingName,
                GZipMessageEncodingPolicyConstants.GZipEncodingNamespace));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        CustomBinding custom = new CustomBinding(new WebHttpBinding());
        for (int i = 0; i < custom.Elements.Count; i++)
        {
            if (custom.Elements[i] is WebMessageEncodingBindingElement)
            {
                WebMessageEncodingBindingElement webBE = (WebMessageEncodingBindingElement)custom.Elements[i];
                custom.Elements[i] = new GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement(webBE);
                break;
            }
        }

        return custom;
    }

    class MyContentEncodingBehavior : IEndpointBehavior, IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            HttpResponseMessageProperty resp = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
            resp.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentEncoding] = "gzip";
        }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), GetBinding(), "");
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyContentEncodingBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(baseAddress + "/GetLargeData?size=1000");
        HttpWebResponse resp;
        try
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription);
        foreach (var header in resp.Headers.AllKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", header, resp.Headers[header]);
        }

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot! Feel free to ignore the e-mail I sent you on your blog :)

Comment: Is there a way of implementing it in a web hosted wcf app?

I'm trying to accomplish that using webconfig.

Thanks

Comment: @otaviosoares, you can use a `ServiceHostFactory` for that. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx for more information.