# Most efficient solution for sending multiple files to client from a webservice?

Tags: web-services, file, io, streaming

Wonder what the community says about the most efficient (in terms of I/O and speed) solution for delivering multiple files back from a single request to a webservice would be. The client is not a web browser.

The options I see so far:

- creating a zip archive and streaming it back to the client.
- base64 encoding files an returning array of strings that would need to be decoded by the client.
- Using Mime multipart/related and sending Mime headers for each file in iteration, also potentially streamed back to the client.

Maybe there are others I haven't considered?

CLARIFICATION:

Let's assume the files may be in the 10s of Megabytes, and that memory is around 4G but there are likely other processes and/or simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to consider the bindings ([streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx)) and transports protocols (SOAP, REST). How large is the average file?

Comment: I have to assume files could be get very large.  The request API is currently JSON-RPC but it could be anything. I typically avoid SOAP because it adds additional library requirements for client, etc.

Comment: @FilmJ - if you aren't using streaming - your client would need to buffer the messages in memory - potentially causing a sluggish system. The only way to solve this is by determining more metrics of your system (average file size, client memory, etc.). I also recommend JSON + REST for minimizing communication - but this won't be your bottleneck for this process.

Comment: So to clarify, you recommend that I stream multiple files separated by a MIME boundary and headers?

Comment: @FilmJ - of the options you have listed, that is the route I would go with.

Comment: @SilverNinja Is there an alternative to those options I've missed? Using "streaming" is in two out of the three.  In meantime, I'll start doing test cases with MIME.

Comment: You should use gzip compression via your application server. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402295/wcf-rest-compression.