# WCF Rest Service - Gaining Access to HTTP Response header

Tags: c#, wcf, http, rest

I have a self hosted WCF Rest service that I am using to simulate a service that I do not have access to yet. (See [JSON REST Service: Content-Encoding: gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495913/json-rest-service-content-encoding-gzip))  I gziped my response, but have not found a way to set the Content-Encoding within the HTTP response header.  Is there a way to get to the HTTP header object so I can set this field?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can access the response headers in your service method via the current [WebOperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.aspx):

```
var response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
```