# Compressing payload data in REST client call

Tags: ruby, api, optimization, compression, rest-client

Let say I have a bulk of text which needs to be pushed to a server thru REST api interface.

I also have a large volume of data/records to get pushed.

I am thinking that if we use compression technique then we can reduce the latency of data transfer.

**Can this be done by including "Content-encoding' in my REST api request though the public API provided my the server did not specify CE option?**

### Edit

In particular I need to figure out how to do this using rest-client gem in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** the REST API allows the use of compression on the request and the response, using the standards defined by the [HTTP 1.1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-23). And this is by using `Accept-Encoding` to tell the server what compression the client supports and the header `Content-Encoding` to describe the compression of the body. You may also check those links :

[Enable HTTP Compression for Requests](https://serverfault.com/questions/56700/is-it-possible-to-enable-http-compression-for-requests)

[JSON REST Service: Content-Encoding: gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495913/json-rest-service-content-encoding-gzip)

[WCF REST Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402295/wcf-rest-compression)

Comment: Thanks @Salem Querdani. Any idea on how to do this in rest-client gem in ruby?